# Show ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript before Response.Redirect

Tags: c#

I want to show a message via "ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript" then redirect to another page but the problem is I really need to use "Response.Redirect" here not any other code to go to that other page and this would cancel scriptManager...

is there a way to fix this without changing "Response.Redirect" part?

I use the following code:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('my message')", true);
Response.Redirect("DropDownMenu.aspx");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to redirect the user to the next page then why don't you put this code in javascript itself and use `window.location` for redirection like this

```
string scriptText = "alert('my message'); window.location='" + Request.ApplicationPath + "dropdownmenu.aspx'";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", scriptText, true);
```

Comment: I can't use javascript for going to another page here...I really need it to be server side...thanks though

Comment: I'm using this part for handling an exception in an semi-recursive codes so if I use javascript to go to another page the code keep executing till the end and I can't use "break" to stop them

Answer (score 2):

if you want to redirect to the next page after clicking on the alert Message, you can use the `javascript` instead of using `Response.Redirect()`

Try This:

```
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,this.GetType(),"alertMessage",
    "alert('my message'); window.location='" + 
    Request.ApplicationPath + "DropDownMenu.aspx';",true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having issues with Dev using a Web Application under the Default Web Site and Prod using the same code directly under Default Web Site (No virtual directory).

If directly under Default Web Site, Request.ApplicationPath is null and caused the URL for the redirect to be https://Sub1/PageToGoTo.aspx.  I want to navigate to https://contoso.com/Sub1/PageToGoTo.aspx.

Here is my code and I hope it helps:

```
string appPath = String.Empty;
if(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath.Length > 1)
{ appPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath; }

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "redirect",
"alert('" + sb.ToString() + "'); window.location='" + appPath + /Sub1/PageToGoTo.aspx';", true);
```